# Change in enthalpy of an adiabatic process

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

So we define the change in enthalpy as the amount of heat exchanged by the system. For an adiabatic process, heat exchanged is zero.
However, enthalpy is also defined as the integral of $C_p dT$ which is not zero. If there something I'm missing?

Comment: "we define the change in enthalpy as the amount of heat exchanged by the system". What? No we don't

$$dH = VdP + TdS = VdP + Q$$

If there is no change in pressure, you're right. But in an adiabatic process the pressure does change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enthalpy is **not** defined as the amount of heat exchanged by the system.  Enthalpy is a physical property of the material comprising the system rather than a characteristic of any particular process the the system is subjected to.  It is defined as H=U+PV, where U is the internal energy of the material, P is the pressure, and V is the volume of material.  We can express enthalpy (per unit mass of material) as a function of its temperature T and pressure P as H=H(T,P).  The heat capacity Cp is defined as the rate of change of H with respect to T at constant P.